# Jitterbit in salesforce

Tags: jitterbit

I am using Jitterbit in salesforce but I don't know Jitterbit Script and have no idea how to use it and why we use it and what are the advantages of using script.

Comment: Hi Rajan, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What exactly are you trying to ask? What research have you done so far? The point of SFSE is to ask *specific* questions which can receive a concise answer, and so this question is likely to be closed as off topic if left as currently written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jitterbit scrip is mainly used to enhance the standard features of jitterbit. Lets say you have some data from a external database that you want to bring into salesforce. You want to add the values from two fields and load that added value into a field in salesforce. You would accomplish this using some scripting in the field mapping.

There are some more complicated examples for how to use scripts in jitterbit but that is something you can learn more about by going to Jitterbits formula builder site. There you can see all the scripting methods that jitterbit has that should give you some idea as to what you can do in jitterbit's scripting tool. https://success.jitterbit.com/display/DOC/Formula+Builder